# Subject-verb inversion when subject isn't clear

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

I just felt like writing the following sentence:

> n^k distinct configurations has a 2dfa(k).

It's natural formulation would be "a 2dfa(k) has n^k distinct configurations", but its after 2AM, and I guess I felt fancy. My question is, is the above sentence in blockquote alright?

My suspicion arose due to "n^k distinct configurations" not having any syntactical indication that it is **not** the subject, and "2dfa(k)" instead is. Maybe, I thought, one should avoid subject-verb inversions even more in such sentences.

Comment: You mean like _A good man was James Black_, with stress on _good man_, and falling intonation on _James Black_? That's archaic and overly dramatic. Certainly not mathematical, if you're intending to publish.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yeah, similar to your example in terms of intonation. I think your sentence cannot be misunderstood with inversion, however. Mine, when inverted, can also sound like the "n^k distinct configurations" might have raised $1k and bought themselves a 2dfa(k), except that the verb is not well conjugated. (It will only appear on slides of a seminar, the only audience being the department.)

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's total gibberish.

Comment: Its 'natural formulation' is much clearer. Until I read you comment in reply to John Lawler I tended towards the opinion of @HotLicks. I'd use the 'natural formulation'.

Comment: As Hot Licks says, it's just gibberish.